# How can I properly observe network state from a class with no lifecycle?

Tags: android, kotlin, caching, android-livedata

I'm trying to implement a caching functionality with Room, and for this, I want to observe the network state in real time using the connectivity manager. When the network is available, I fetch data from the API, save it into the database, and then load it back to display it on the UI. If the connection is lost, it should just load the previously cached data. The problem is that even though I can see the saved data with the database inspector, it doesn't show up on the UI unless i restart the app. So this means that the saving was actually successful. By the way `getmovieList()` is called from a ViewModel with ViewModelScope. If I comment out the network-checking condition, the app works well.

I tried both livedata with observeForever and also flow, but for some reason i get the above result with both. What i'm doing wrong?

```kotlin
enum class Status {
    Available, Lost, Losing, Unavailable
}
```

```kotlin
class NetworkObserver(context: Context) {

    private var connectivityManager =
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    

    fun observe(): Flow<Status> {
        return callbackFlow {
            val calback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
                    super.onAvailable(network)
                    launch { trySend(Status.Available) }
                }

                override fun onLosing(network: Network, maxMsToLive: Int) {
                    super.onLosing(network, maxMsToLive)
                    launch { trySend(Status.Losing) }
                }

                override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                    super.onLost(network)
                    launch { trySend(Status.Lost) }
                }

                override fun onUnavailable() {
                    super.onUnavailable()
                    launch { trySend(Status.Unavailable) }
                }
            }
            connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(calback)
            awaitClose {
                connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(calback)
            }
        }
            .distinctUntilChanged()
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class movieRepositoryImpl(
    private val movieService: movieService,
    private val movieDao: movieDao,
    private val context: Context
) : movieRepository {
    private val networkObserver = NetworkObserver(context.applicationContext)

    override suspend fun getmovieList(): List<movieModel> {
        networkObserver.observe().onEach { status ->
            if (status == Status.Available || status == Status.Losing) {
                val response = movieService.getmovieList()
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val movieDtoList = response.body()
                    movieDtoList?.let {
                        val movieWithTitlesList = tomovieEntityList(it.movieListData)
                        movieDao.insertmovieListWithTitles(movieWithTitlesList)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            .launchIn(CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO))

        val movieModelList =
            movieModel.asmovieModelList(movieDao.getAll())
        return movieModelList.ifEmpty { emptyList() }
    }
}
```

Comment: You `launchIn` your network observer flow instead of waiting for it to complete. Haven't you noticed your `getMovieList` returns almost immediately before any network query is performed?

Comment: Yes, step through the logic of your `getmovieList()` and you'll see the logic is not cohesive. It's like you haven't decided how it should behave. This is a suspend function, so the caller expects to simply get a List when calling it. But you are basing the call on a flow of network state that you are firing off asynchronously. What do you want this function to return when the current network state is disconnected?

Comment: What should happen if the current network state is disconnected? What do you want to do once a List actually is retrieved? Because currently, you keep fetching Lists of Movies in the background for the lifetime of your app once this function is called, and leak more and more of these coroutines that collect copies of the network state and make network requests as this function is called repeatedly in the same process. And ultimately, as Pawel says, you don't wait for any of these events in the current code before returning from your function.

Comment: @Pawel i tried after you comment, maybe i was did it wrong, but it didn't change much ( val fetch= CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async ) { networkObserver.observe().onEach.....etc}.await

Comment: @Tenfour04 #1 load data from the db. If this is the very first time running the app, then return an empty list. #2 (mapping to model class type) and display it on the ui. So eventually what is displayed on the ui, is always comes from the db. Its just if i have connection i "update" the database content based on the api's response. So supposedly if we run the app 1st time with no connection, it should just return an empty list. (Because we haven't hada single succesfull api query).Flow is for deciding network current state, suspend is for not to freeze UI